# write unsorted consecutive strings array sorted into a file

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, performance, sorting

I got an array of strings containing unordered consecutive numbers(ranged from 0 to n) 
e.g - `[7a, 1b, 2c, 0d, 6e, 5f, 3g, 4h]`
and I want to write the number by order into a file

after example : 
`0d`
`1b`
`2c`
`3g`
`4h`
`5f`
`6e`
`7a`

and I was trying to find a way to do it both fast and without taking too much space
I found a way that I can do it in O(n) space complexity and O(n) performance
(I create an array with n cells and insert each number to his cell number)
arr[cell] = cell

but I am looking for a better way to do it, if you could help I would be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: "I found a way that I can do it" so, post it, along with what you think is wrong or may be suspect for improvement.  What sort of "numbers" are `3g`, `4h` ? They're clearly not base-16. Are you really sorting *strings* ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the numbers are consecutive,you don't need an array at all.

you only need find the *smallest* and *largest* elements in the array. Once you know the `min` and `max`, you can write the numbers in the range into the file. This is still O(n) time but no additional space complexity. If `min` is always `0` then you only need to the laragest number in the array.

Comment: Also if the numbers numbers indeed start at zero, are unique, and leave no holes, you only need the size of the array. The numbers are all within `[0..(size-1)]`, thereby making the original array somewhat meaningless beyond knowing its size.

Comment: @BlueMoon  I edited the question, sorry that I wasn't clear enough

Comment: @WhozCraig  I edited the question, sorry that I wasn't clear enough

Comment: @GeorgeMeaze Hmmm..please don't significantly alter the question. In the future, may be post a new question if you need to. Now, I think you are left with using an auxiliary array (O(n) space & O(n) time) OR sorting the original aray - O(nlogn).

Answer (score 0):

Since the numbers are consecutives, there's no need to validate there are in the array so you could use `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` to know the array length, and then you could do a for loop like so:

```
int writeNum(int* nums){
  FILE *f = fopen("yourfile.txt");
  if(f == NULL) return 0;
  for(int n = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]), i = 0; i < n; i++){
    fprintf(f,"%d\n",i);
  }
fclose(f);
return 1;
}
```